# E python como parar uma Thread especifica (ou todas) em loop while

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, while, multithreading

Como parar uma, ou todas as Threads no python por ID (exemplo)

Estou elaborando um programa que deve executar alguns loops buscando informação em tempo real.
Porém, quando algum deles encontrar algo a thread que executa ele deve ser finalizada, ou mesmo todas as threads.

Segue exemplo do código:

```
def log(palavras):
    while True:

        ... # processos diversos aqui
        
        if palavra == 'Gato':
            # parar thread relacionada a esse loop
            # OU parar todas as threads
            break
                
    ... # Continua o processo do script

def iniciaThreads():
    animais = ('Gato', 'Cachorro', 'Papagaio') # Exemplo com 3 items, mas podem ser vários

    for pet in animais:
        t = Thread(target=log, args=[pet])
        procAnimais.append(t)

    # Inicia todas as Threads
    for x in procAnimais:
        x.start()

iniciaThreads()
```

Não sei se existe, mas pensei em alguma forma de enviar via parâmetro o ID da thread para a função que faz o loop e encerrar ela lá:

```
t = Thread(target=log, args=[pet, id_thread])
```

E no loop quando atingir alguma condição executar:

```
...
id_thread.stop()
break
```

Comment: De uma lida em ['threading.Thread.join()'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

Comment: @AugustoVasqueseu já havia lido mas não soube usar. Assim como outros diversos exemplos que não funcionou dentro de um loop. Mas obrigado por compartilhar.

Comment: Eu gosto de fazer o seguinte. Crio uma classe usando o padrão de projeto Singleton. Ao invés de usar `while True`, uso `while var_no_singleton`, em uma determinada condição atualizo a variável e pronto a thread que tinha aquela `var_no_singleton` vai sair do loop. Caso sejam várias, sua `var_no_singleton` seria um dicionário...